# Kubernetes Service - reaching localhost

Tags: java, spring, docker, kubernetes

I am trying to expose my two springboot applications to the external network which are on AWS storage and I'm getting my head blown because I can't make one of them reach another one. The first application, let's call it A, it returns the rest page with a number:123, the second one is returning the name of host specified in deployment file of first application: let's say `hostname: datahost`. It has a method `/getnumber` which returns this number when put into web browser. It's working on 8080 port.

The point is that the second application has a return statement of "http://datahost:8080/getnumber", which should be returning the result of first application `/getnumber` result.
Unfortunately the return statement is:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
>   I/O error on GET request for "http://datahost:8080/getnumber": datahost; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: datahost

Can u guys explain or give a tip how to make those applications be visible for eachother? They are both in two another pods and in the same node.
Furthermore if I use it on localhost on a computer and forward it to localhost:8080/getnumber, then it works.

Comment: please add manifests for your deployments and services to the question

Answer (score 0):

In order to make two PODs connect to each other, you need to create a `Service` for your pods.

As a simple example, you can run a command similar to this one:

```
kubectl -n <your namespace> expose pod <your pod name> --port 8080
```

You'll end up having an object of type `Service` created and you will be able to reach your pod by using the service name as the hostname.

Again, this is just an example and you probably want to expose your `deployment` rather than your `pod`

More details here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

Comment: Sorry, I've forgotten to mention that I've created two independent services for both deployments. The type is: LoadBalancer cuz NodePort can't be reached externally. Service with LoadBalancer type creates an external address for service to be reached.

Comment: Ok so you can use your service name to reach your pods. What does `kubectl get svc` return?

Comment: NAME                        TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP        PORT(S)          AGE                                                                                    | 
dataservice-service         LoadBalancer   100.66.121.125   a45ff9fd3fa0a...   8080:31246/TCP   15h                                                     |
helloworldservice-service   LoadBalancer   100.69.44.37     a49869df2fa0a...   8081:31594/TCP   15h

Comment: You should be able to use `dataservice-service` or `dataservice-service.<namespace>` as hostname to reach your pods, then.

Comment: Error. Name not resovled is being responsed when I try to get by dataservice-service:8080/getnumber

Comment: Are the two pods in the same namespace?

Comment: They are both using the same default namespace. It's not declared in their deployment/service files so.

Comment: that's really weird, as long as your `kube-dns` service is healthy, service names HAVE to be resolved within a pod. I suggest running a network troubleshooting pod in the default namespace and debugging your DNS resolution.

Comment: I guess we misunderstood each other. In one pod, there is an application dataservice with "hostname: dataservice" and exposed port 8080. In the second pod, there is an app helloworld which tries to use followed link: dataservice:8080/getDate but it says that dataservice is an unknown host.

Comment: In fact, "dataservice" doesn't seem a correct name in your environment to me. That's why I suggested to change it to "dataservice-service".

Comment: Yes, but even after changing it to dataservice-service, this had no impact so

Comment: So I get back to my latest suggestion: «I suggest running a network troubleshooting pod in the default namespace and debugging your DNS resolution.»

Comment: that seems to be weird but after changing the name of hostname parameter to testhostname, then it started to work properly. In that case the name conflict were appeared. Thank you for your help :)